# Tomcat blank page

Tags: tomcat

I'm using linux and tomcat6.

When I open with browser `http://my-ip-address:8080/my-app/`, it shows a blank page.

```
INFO: Server startup in 6252 ms
May 6, 2013 10:39:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:617)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

How can I resolved it?

Comment: you already have something running on port 8080, either stop that , or change tomcat's port and then try to start it

Comment: @Satya : I killed all process on port 8080, then restart tomcat. But nothing happen, it still say Address already in use.

Comment: Try "netstat" and find out which service is using the port number.

Comment: @TheUnlucky Not a duplicate.

Comment: Are u familiar with linux?

Comment: @TheUnlucky The port in question is 8005. Are you reading what's written here at all? It's right there in the stack trace, and also in an answer.

Comment: @TheUnlucky You need to read the whole question, not just the first two lines. Port 8005 is mentioned three lines later. See also the answer below.

Comment: @TheUnlucky I don't think you do. Tomcat uses port 8005 for shutdown. It also uses port 8009 for AJP, 8443 for HTTPS, etc etc etc. It's all configurable. You're jumping to conclusions without knowing enough about it.

Comment: Thanks FYI :) Will keep  improve it @EJP

Answer (score 1):

You already have something running on port *8005*, just like it says in the stack trace.

Comment: Find the process that using port 8005. It is almost certainly another Tomcat. If you're trying to run several Tomcats at once you have to make a lot of port/address adjustments in server.xml and the entire question would be off topic, belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'But please show me how can I stop that?' You can simply kill the associated process or stop the service using Task manager (or tool like ProcessExplorer on Windows) and 'kill #pid' on linux.